# How to parse javascript data list with R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I use R to parse html code, and I would like to know the most efficient way to sparse the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var utag_data = {
  environnement : "prod",
  device : getDevice(),
  displaytype : getDisplay($(window).innerWidth()),
  pagename : "adview",
  pagetype : "annonce"}</script>
```

I started to do this:

```
infos = unlist(xpathApply(page,
                          '//script[@type="text/javascript"]',
                          xmlValue))
infos=gsub('\n|  ','',infos)
infos=gsub("var utag_data = ","",infos)
fromJSON(infos)
```

And the code above returns somthing really weird:

```
$nvironnemen
[1] "prod"

$evic
NULL

$isplaytyp
NULL

$agenam
[1] "adview" etc.
```

I would like to know how to do it very efficient way: how to parse directly the data list in the javascript ?
Thank you.

Comment: The code is doing its work. Nothing wrong with it. Or do you mean not getting `NULL` for keys device and displaytyp?

Comment: OK, in fact, I was surprised that in the output, environnement is transformed to "$nvironnemen", I thought it is was a bug. How could you explain this ?

Answer (score 5):

I didn't try your code, but I think your `gsub()` regexes might be overagressive (which is prbly causing the name munging).

It's possible to run javascript code using the `V8` package, but it 
wont be able to execute the DOM-based `getDevice()` and `getDisplay()`
functions since they don't exist in the V8 engine:

```
library(V8)
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html('<script type="text/javascript">
var utag_data = {
  environnement : "prod",
  device : getDevice(),
  displaytype : getDisplay($(window).innerWidth()),
  pagename : "adview",
  pagetype : "annonce"}</script>')


script <- html_text(html_nodes(pg, xpath='//script[@type="text/javascript"]'))

ctx <- v8()

ctx$eval(script)
## Error: ReferenceError: getDevice is not defined
```

However, you can compensate for that:

```
# we need to remove the function calls and replace them with blanks
# since both begin with 'getD' this is pretty easy:
script <- gsub("getD[[:alpha:]\\(\\)\\$\\.]+,", "'',", script)  

ctx$eval(script)
ctx$get("utag_data")

## $environnement
## [1] "prod"
## 
## $device
## [1] ""
## 
## $displaytype
## [1] ""
## 
## $pagename
## [1] "adview"
## 
## $pagetype
## [1] "annonce"
```

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr for your help. I didn't try to evaluate the functions, so it is perfect ! And in fact, do you know why with json, "environnement" becomes "$nvironnemen" ?

Comment: Could you also please explain what does this regex "getD[[:alpha:]\\(\\)\\$\\.]+," means ? It seems to delete all characters before "()", and in "()". How do you "read" it ? Thank you very much.