# Parse JSON in R using V8 $eval?

Tags: r, v8

If we open chrome developer console (command + option + j), go the javascript console, and enter

```js
JSON.parse('{ "name":"John"}');
```

which returns `{name: "John"}`

but when we run the same javascript in R using V8 (using the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515062/how-to-parse-javascript-data-list-with-r)), it returns a different result

```
library(V8)
ctx <- v8()
ctx$eval("JSON.parse('{\"name\":\"John\"}');")

# "[object Object]"
```

How can we get `V8::eval()` to return the correct result?

#### Note

- The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/V8.pdf) may hold some clues (I've tried a few things from there but nothing successfully)

Comment: Have you tried `ctx$eval("JSON.parse('{\"name\":\"John\"}')")`  (note the missing `;`)

Comment: @sdgfsdh Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it returns `"[object Object]"` (exact same as with the `;`)

Comment: I see. My only other suggestion without digging into the code would be: `ctx$eval("(() => JSON.parse('{\"name\":\"John\"}'))()")`

Comment: @sdgfsdh Thanks. I don't know enough javascript to understand what it does, but unfortunately the result is also `"[object Object]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"[object Object]"` is the result of calling `toString` on a JSON object in JavaScript. `ctx$eval` returns the correct JavaScript object but, before passing it over to R, its `toString` JavaScript method is invoked.

But you will nevertheless be able to *use* the object as expected — you just need to assign it to a variable, e.g.

```
ctx$eval("let result = JSON.parse('{\"name\":\"John\"}');")
```

If you want to get the JSON *into R*, then going via V8 is a huge detour, because the communication between R and V8 is *already* JSON-encoded. Use `jsonlite::fromJSON` instead.

Nevertheless, I guess you could do

```
ctx$get("result")
```

… which internally calls `JSON.stringify` in JavaScript, followed by `jsonlite::fromJSON` in R … so you are going back and forth between object and JSON string several times.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I will use `$get` as you recommend. NB there is a reason I'm taking the detour, only worth reading about if you're really bored and would like a challenge :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305534/parse-json-with-undefined-value